# How to know which type of network I'm using in a USB modem 4G,4G+ or 5G?

Tags: at-command, modem, 5g

How do I translate the results from AT+command like `AT+WS46=?` to the traditional nomenclature of 3G, 4G, 4G+, and 5G?

I'm searching for a simple way to know what connection type the modem I'm working with is, and all the info I get from google searches are in term of UTRAN, EUTRAN, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no AT command uses the terms 3G, 4G, 5G etc.

3G - UTRAN

4G - eUTRAN

5G - NG-RAN